# Access 2010 Find Most Recent Status via SQL

Tags: sql, ms-access

Need list of "ALL" document numbers (k002) with their the most recent maintenance date (lm01_s) and status_code.  The code below finds last date from the entire table and any record with that date.  This is not what I need.  There is only one table.  If I drop the status_code from the equation, this is easy.

```
SELECT k002, lm01_s, status_code
FROM stat_trans
WHERE (lm01_s = ANY (SELECT MAX(lm01_s) FROM stat_trans)) ORDER BY lm01_s;
```

I have also tried this ...

```
SELECT k002, lm01_s, advice_code
FROM romis_stat_trans
WHERE lm01_s IN (((SELECT Max(lm01_s) FROM romis_stat_trans GROUP BY k002)));
```

I have tried so many things that I forget what I have tried.  Everything has been a dead end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a subquery in the `where` clause to return only the records where lm01_s is equal to the max lm01_s.  I found it's important to use a table alias or else Access will confuse the fields.

```
select k002, 
       lm01_s, 
       status_code
from stat_trans
where lm01_s=(select max(sc.lm01_s)
              from stat_trans as sc
              where sc.k002 = stat_trans.k002)
```

Comment: This does the trick.  Thank you!  I will be looking the the use of the alias in the near future.